# Drag/Drop feature in Android is really snappy

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am having trouble using android studio's drag and drop feature. I have no problem getting the items onto the preview mode of the android phone, but when I want to move the palettes, I can't seem to be able to place them where I want. A lot of times I will place let's say a TextView, and it will snap to a different location an inch away. Anyone know if any solutions?

Comment: @AHoneyBustard I don't think there is code to show. The question is about the XML editor of Android Studio

Comment: Yes correct. There is no code to show as it is about the XML editor of Android Studio.

Comment: What do you mean "an inch away"? The editor places in pixels almost always. What is the root layout? RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you know a way to un-snappy the editor, it's time to get to know the XML Text Editor, next tab over in Android Studio.

The way I get round the snappy side is in there: use the `"android:layout_below="@+id/example"` and it's brethren. Unless you have a massive amount of elements, this is very doable.